# Altium: How to hide rats nests?

Tags: altium

When there are a lot of connections and nets, these rats nest of nets can be a bit troublesome during layout. Does anybody know how to remove/hide the rats nests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by going to your layer set properties (click the colored box at the bottom left of your screen):

[image]

On the right-hand side uncheck the box labeled "Show" next to "Default color for new nets":

[image]

This will hide all airwires at once.

Comment: I have to mention that it works but the rats nets will come back if going from 2d to 3

Answer (score 7):

In Altium Designer 16.x, while viewing the PCB go to View > Connections > Hide All.

This will hide all of the ratnest nets. If you select a component that *one* component's nets will be shown as a convenience, but other than that I think this solves your problem. I find it useful to enable this option during initial placement of a crowded design.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on a net, and choose **Net Actions >> Hide Nets**.

[image]

Comment: I want to remove them all , not one by one.