# How to hide selected rats nest lines in Altium?

Tags: pcb-design, altium, layout

When you first start to place your components on the PCB all of the rat nest lines are total chaos.

When I use Eagle I like to hide selected rat nest lines (namely VCC and GND) as these will generally connect to an internal power plane or polygon pour. This de-clutters the rat nest lines and allows me to then focus on the general inter-component connections.

**How do I hide selected rat nest lines in Altium PCB?**

Note: This question is similar to [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/239536/altium-how-to-hide-rats-nests) but I only want to hide selected rat nest lines, not all of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a shorter/quicker way than @Rev1.0's as well:

1. Right click the net you want to hide
2. Go to Net Actions in the menu, and press Hide Nets.

**Shortcut** (as everything in Altium has a shortcut): 
*Right-click, N, H.*

Image showing this by [Bence Kaulics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/56348/bence-kaulics) on a [different question here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/239542/104097) on the site:

[image: Image that shows right-click menu]

Answer (score 1):

1. In the PCB document, go to the PCB side panel.
2. Select `Nets` from the dropdown menu.
3. Select `<All Nets>` in the Net Class box.
4. Right click the net to hide and select Properties.

[image]

5. Check "Hide connections".

As you pointed out, this is especially useful for power nets if you are using planes. In that case, the power nets air wires are not of much interest during placement.