# Altium - Hiding connections for a particular component in the PCB designer

Tags: pcb, altium

my question is simple: can I in Altium PCB Designer hide the connections for only a particular component?

[image]

I tried whit "View->Connections->Hide Component Nets" but this hides **all** the connections for every component on the board. I want hide only the connections from the *header* component to the others and not the connection from the IC, for example, and the other component on the top of the board.

Is it possible?

To explain better, this is my actual situation:

[image]

If I make "View->Connections->Hide Component Nets" or "N->H->O" all connection disapear (even for the IC on the top):

[image]

But I want this final situation (I photoshopped the image!):

[image]

Comment: Then you mean you want hide partial nets on one component?

Comment: Just press N->H->O, then press the header, then the nets from/to header are hidden.

Comment: I suppose this is what you need: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/239542/56348

Comment: @diverger the effect is the same to "View->Connections->Hide Component Nets". I edited the post with other images to explain better.

Comment: @BenceKaulics No, the command hide the whole net. I want hide only the connection from header to IC and no from IC to other components. I edited the post with other images to explain better.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why?

Comment: @uint128_t Just for my curiosity. I thought that if I have a very complex PCB and I want focus only to a group of connections to create the traks, if there is a component with high number of connections, they may confuse during the work. So if there is the option I asked for....

Comment: It seems Altium assume you want to hide all the nets on the PCB which connected to the component you selected. And for this command, it seems Altium only works on nets but not on connections.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I searched on the web a solution to the problem and I found that in Altium there isn't a feature wich hide the connections for only one component. However I found (in the Altium forum) two escamotage to obtain it:

1. > The easiest way to hide net connections to a single footprint would be
   >   to temporarily remove those pins from the net.  Just be sure to
   >   "update from schematic" at some later point in the project.

   It seems the faster way to hide temporally the connection for the component.
   [image]
2. > You can get the result using the *From-To* feature, but it would take
   >   some time to setup. Try this [page](http://www.altium.com/documentation/17.1/display/ADES/PCB_Pnl-PCB((PCB+-+From-To+Editor))_AD) for more information.

These solutions seem to be the better ways but any other suggestion are welcome.